# API Post Data to Middleware

Tags: api, post

Anyone know how I can test posting data to this [url](http://powersource.braindongle.com/lead-manager/lead/new/omgpost/sessions/)? I was given the link by the IT supervisor and trying to have the data posted to the following link by submitting the following form. He said it would accept anything I send it

Answer (score 1):

Could could do this via curl:

```
curl -X POST -d "data=anything_i_send_it" http://powersource.braindongle.com/lead-manager/lead/new/omgpost/sessions/
```

Or using another HTTP tool like [Hurl.it](http://www.hurl.it/?method=POST&url=http://powersource.braindongle.com/lead-manager/lead/new/omgpost/sessions/)

Or using a Chrome extension like [Postman](http://getpostman.com) or [REST Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

[Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US) is an easy way to do it. It's a free chrome extension that can form http requests with data.